# php Curl clicked links

Tags: php, curl

I need any link that has a "a href=" tag when clicked to be received via curl. I can't hard code these links as they are from a dynamic site so could be anything. How would I achieve this?

Thanks

Edit: Let me explain more. I have an app on my pc that uses a web front end. It catalogs files and gives yo options to rename delete etc. I want to add a public view however if I put it as is online then anyone can delete rename files. If I curl the pages I can remove the menu bars and editing options through the use of a different css. That part all works. The only part that isn't working is if I click on a link on the page it directs me back to the original link address and that defeats the point as the menu bars are back. I need it to curl the clicked links. Hope that makes more sense..

Here is my code that fetches the original link and curls that and changes the css to point to my own css. It points the java script to the original as I dont need to change that. I now need to make the "a href" links on the page when clicked be called by curl and not go to the original destination

```
<?php


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://192.168.0.14:8081/home/');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$curl_response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

//Change link url

$link = $curl_response;

$linkgo = '/sickbeard_public';
$linkfind = 'href="';
$linkreplace = 'href="' . $linkgo ;

$link = str_replace($linkfind, $linkreplace, $link);

//Change js url
$js = $link;

$jsgo = 'http://192.168.0.14:8081';
$jsfind = 'src="';
$jsreplace = 'src="' . $jsgo ;

$js = str_replace($jsfind, $jsreplace, $js);


//Fix on page link errors
$alink = $js;
$alinkgo = 'http://192.168.0.14:8081/';
$alinkfind = 'a href="/sickbeard_public/';
$alinkreplace = 'a href="' . $alinkgo ;

$alink = str_replace($alinkfind, $alinkreplace, $alink);

//Echo page back
echo $alink;

?>
```

Comment: are you looking to make a proxy?

Comment: please paste your code in code block...

Answer (score 0):

You could grab all the URLs using a regular expression

```
// insert general warning about how parsing HTML using regex is evil :-)
preg_match('/href="([^"]+)"/', $html, $matches);
$urls = array_slice($matches, 1);

// Now just loop through the array and fetch the URLs with cUrl...
```

Answer (score 0):

While I can't imagine why you would do that I think you should use ajax.
Attach an event on every a tag and send them to a script on your server where the magic of curl would happen.
Anyway you should explain why you need to fetch data with curl.

Comment: How would the code for this look? Call the curl script "curllink.php"

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand your question you need to get the contents of URL via CURL... so here is the solution

```
<a href="<?php print $my_url; ?>" id="my_link">Click here to get via curl </a>
```

Then attach an event with the above `<a>` tag, e.g. in JQuery

```
$("#my_link").click(function(){
   var target_url = $(this).attr("href");
   //Send an ajax call to some of your page like cURL_wrapper.php with target_url as parameter in get
});
```

then in `cURL_wrapper.php` do follwoing

```
<?php
//Get the $target_url here from $_GET[];
$ch = curl_init($your_domain");
$fp = fopen("$target_url", "r");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```